# Nginx redirect with subdomain and path

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

Using Nginx I want to redirect from **a list of old URLs to new.**
I have a huge list like so.

few examples

```
https://subold.domain.com/old-path-0 -> https://subnew.domain.com/new-path
https://subold.domain.com/old-path-1 -> https://subnew.domain.com/new-path-alpha
https://subold.domain.com/old-path-2 -> https://subnew.domain.com/new-path-gamma
https://subold.domain.com/old-path-3 -> https://subnew.domain.com/new-path-2
```

Answer (score 0):

In your old domain configuration:

```
rewrite ^/old-path$ http://subnew.domain.com/new-path permanent;
```

Comment: thanks, I have made an update in question, the path actually varies, for which I have a list.